# Can all time zones be represented as 'Area/Location'?

Tags: python, timezone

If I look at

```py
import zoneinfo
zoneinfo.available_timezones()
```

in Python, then there are:

- 'Area/Location' time zones, such as `'US/Mountain'`,
- abbreviated time zones, such as 'GMT',
- other time zones, such as `'Cuba'`

Does 'UTC' and 'Area/Location' cover all time zones?

Context: I'm making a library which wraps pandas, and would like to validate what can be passed to pandas as a time zone. Pandas currently accepts fixed offsets like '+01:00' and also abbreviations like `'GMT'` and `'Cuba'`.

If I restricted it to `'UTC'` or `'Area/Location'` time zones, would that cut off any time zones? All the ones I've seen have an `'Area/Location'` equivalent: for example, instead of `'GMT'` users can pass `'Europe/London'` if they wanted UK time, and instead of `'Cuba'` they can pass `'America/Havana'`

Comment: There are way more cases than just splitting up 24 hours into +/- 12 hr offsets. Time zones are not a technical problem -- they are _political_ and super complicated. The artificial restriction you're considering doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

Comment: Exactly - so I don't want users passing '+01:00' as a time zone, I want them to pass something like 'Africa/Lagos', which will deal with the political issues such as time zone changes / DST

Comment: You're basically asking, "can I omit certain timezones from [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) and still express all possible timezone configurations?" to which I'm saying "probably not". Take a stab at the list and give it a shot? Not sure why you feel a need to have any restrictions in the first place...

Comment: @Kache that list seems to verify the assertion made in the question - every zone in the list without a `/` is either a link or has instructions on what to use instead.

Comment: Yup, exactly. I feel the need for this because of the number issues which time zones such as 'CET'  / 'GMT+1' and the like can cause